# How do I get this responsive css to work on Gmail for Android?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

I slightly modified a responsive email template created by Litmus.com for my own project. It behaves as I expect in my browser (Chrome) when viewed in the developer's tools mobile view. However, the design looks very different when viewed in the Gmail app for Android 7.1.2 Nougat (not imap account). I'd like to see what's going on but I'm unable to look under the hood since there's no way to see the code rendered on the App.

For example, the text isn't center aligning, the images looks small, the button isn't spanning the full width. Here's a screenshot of a side by side comparison of Mobile view in Chrome vs. the Gmail App for Android.

[image]

I've read from various sources that responsive css via media queries are supported on the Gmail app so I'm very confused. I've been working on this for quite some time now and feel stuck. Any help with a solution or advice in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Here is my code. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMoNqm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: for e mailer you can use XHTML0.1 it's working batter ?

Comment: I changed it to <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> but that didn't affect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that if there is spaces in the media query then Gmail doesnt work that well. I have removed spaces around

```
@media screen and (max-width:525px), screen and (max-device-width:525px)     
{
}
```

This is the code I use which works well in Gmail App android.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
.wrapper{background-color:#ff0000 !important;}
}
```

I tested it just now and it works. My Gmail App version is `7.8.13.166937981`.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: I compressed the responsive css like this:

Comment: I compressed the responsive css like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvRZzL

But it isn't working for me. I'm using the same version of Gmail that you have and on Android 7.1.2. Am I removing the spaces in the CSS incorrectly?

If it isn't too much to ask, will you show me a screenshot of how it looks and how you removed the spaces to make it work?

Comment: i still see spaces `max-width: 525px` remove the space before 525px in both cases and try again.

Comment: I tried that as well but no luck. As a test, I sent both versions to my friend's gmail account and it looked no different on his phone as well. He has the most updated os and gmail app on his Pixel phone. What model phone and os version are you using?

Comment: In a worst case scenario, I've heard some people use tricks to force the email to look the same as the desktop version on Gmail. Do you think that this is a viable method?

Comment: Motorola Nexus 6 Android 7.1.1 . I will test your html shortly to see if there can be any fixes that will work

Comment: I just checked your code on my nexus and [here are the screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/Uv8ej). I Used your code from codepen.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is the email account gmail to which you are sending to?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for my roommate and I's phones. This is driving me insane!! However, Thank you so much for going out of your way with the screenshots. It's somewhat comforting to know that it is working for some. Yes, they are both gmail addresses and opened in the Gmail app for Android.

Comment: If its not working then maybe force desktop but do have a query that work for Gmail app so it will work for ones that do read the media query

Comment: I'll do that. I contacted Litmus to let them know that their templates (which are supposed to be bulletproof) is breaking in my case. Is there a particular method you normally use to force the desktop version to load?

Comment: you can use spaces, image with min, max width and width set to a specific size. Give it a try.

Comment: if you want me to check anything look for syfer_darknight on twitter and you can find me

Comment: Appreciate it Syfer.

Comment: Hi Syfer, I found out that Mailchimp is forcing some type of Email Purifier and that this may be the reason why my tests weren't working. I very much wish Mailchimp would leave my code alone. It works fine on my devices when I send it from Putsmail.

Comment: Think it would be best to contact them and tell them of the issue you are facing so they can give you solutions or change their backend to accommodate them.

Comment: I have but they're ofcourse unwilling to change their system.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your email is stacking columns via hybrid coding, but the alignment via the media queries is not taking effect. This is likely because **media query support *was not* extended to every Gmail email product.** Depending on the Android version and email type (is your email a POP account?), anything in the media queries will still be ignored by some Gmail products.

Here is a quick breakdown of where the rollout stands:
[image]

[More info and updated charts on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design)

Comment: I'm using Gmail app for Android 7.1.2 Nougat with a standard gmail account to test. It's not a imap or pop account as far as I'm aware.